# Android: xml selector for button

Tags: java, android, xml, selector, imagebutton

I'm trying to use an xml selector to change the image of imagebuttons when they are pressed but I've been faceing a few problems. First of all, the images appear with different dimensions on the screen, and secondly the button changes color only when clicked, but not when it is active.

This is the xml of the **layout** with the imagebuttons:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/coupon_filter_btns"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:background="#a7a7a7"
    android:weightSum="7"
    >


    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/filter_greece"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/greece"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/greece"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
        />
     <ImageButton/>
     <ImageButton/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Below is the selector called **greece.xml**:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:drawable="@drawable/greece_active" android:state_selected="true"></item>

<item android:drawable="@drawable/greece_active" android:state_focused="true"></item>

<item android:drawable="@drawable/greece_active" android:state_pressed="true"></item>

<item android:drawable="@drawable/filter_white_greece"></item>

</selector>
```

And this is the java code where the button is used:

```
 ImageView filterGreece = (ImageView) kati.findViewById(R.id.filter_greece);
    filterGreece.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.greece);
    filterGreece.setOnClickListener(new ViewListeners(this.getContext()).new OneFragmentFilters(OneFragment.this)  ) ;
```

Comment: "the button changes color only when clicked, but not when it is active" can you explain this further?

Comment: I would like the button to have another color when the tab is active, not only when clicked

Answer (score 0):

Ok first there Erro in your XML

you Just set drawable as background Not Src

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/coupon_filter_btns"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:background="#a7a7a7"
    android:weightSum="7"
    >


    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/filter_greece"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
         android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/greece"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
        />
  </LinearLayout>
```

second selector will work fine without

```
filterGreece.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.greece);
```

so remove this Line

Comment: Thank you for your reply, it has been really helpful. As I mentioned above, I would like the buttons to remain active when the screen they represent is displayed. Any idea how I could do that?